# responsive image with div and css (no img tag)

Tags: html, css, response

I have a code like this:

```
<div class="wrap">

</div>

.wrap {
background-image: url("woody.jpg");
background-size: cover;
display: block;
min-height: 300px;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
```

this code works but it crops images. I do not want it. I want display full height and widgh with pure css.

(width and height are not fixed. width is according parent,height is full according current width )

also I do not want use img tag like [this](http://thenewcode.com/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design).

Is it possible?

Comment: I think your best best is to use percentages for the width and height.  At 100% for both the image should be the maximum size.  If you did a simple ratio you could compute the change in width which then also becomes the height value.

Comment: thanks but I test it before. it just works for square images.

Comment: `background-size:cover` means "make sure the image always fills the area and crop off the overflow". This W3Schools page has more information on background-size http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-size: contain;
```

`background-size: contain;` Will not crop, so the full image is displayed, adapts to the div size

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-size and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size for more information.

Answer (score 0):

this will help to you.but we don't know what is the exact size you want.so you have to change the size of `div` in the code as your need.try this and set your image `url` or `path`.change the `value` of `div`'s `width` and `height` as your need.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Image</title>
<style>
  body{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
  }

  div.imageContainer
  {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
  }

  div.imageContainer img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px black;
    margin: 2%;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="imageContainer">
   <img src="your image url or path">
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```